# Подскажите пожалуйста, как в mysql из одного столбца вывести данные в несколько столбцов?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица в которой весь процесс обращений записан по времени:

```
appeal_id    client_id        dt                       text
1              111       2022-03-14 15:11:45         Обращение
2              111       2022-03-14 15:12:51         Отказ
3              111       2022-03-31 13:30:54         Отказ
4              111       2022-03-14 15:18:36         Нет документов
```

Каждое обращение и результат записан в один столбец. Мне необходимо данные представить в разные столбцы и по времени:

```
client_id  Обращение         Отказ             Одобрено          Проведено      
111        14.03.2022 15:11  14.03.2022 15:12  (null)            (null)     
111        14.03.2022 15:16  14.03.2022 15:17  (null)            (null)            
111        31.03.2022 13:30  31.03.2022 13:30  (null)            (null)     
111        31.03.2022 13:32  (null)            31.03.2022 13:33  01.04.2022 0:00
```

Код на создание таблицы с данными:

```sql
CREATE TABLE appeal(
    appeal_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    client_id INT,
    dt datetime,
    text VARCHAR (30)
);

INSERT INTO appeal (client_id, dt, text) VALUES 
('111', '2022-03-14 15:11:45.000', 'Обращение'),
('111', '2022-03-14 15:12:51.000',  'Отказ'),
('111', '2022-03-31 13:30:54.000',  'Отказ'),
('111', '2022-03-14 15:18:36.000',  'Нет документов'),
('111', '2022-03-31 13:30:05.000',  'Обращение'),
('111', '2022-03-31 13:34:28.000',  'Есть документы'),
('111', '2022-04-01 00:00:00.000',  'Проведено'), 
('111', '2022-03-14 15:16:22.000',  'Обращение'),
('111', '2022-03-14 15:17:36.000',  'Отказ'),
('111', '2022-03-31 13:32:47.000',  'Обращение'),
('111', '2022-03-31 13:33:47.000',  'Одобрено');
```

то, что я пытался сделать:

```sql
select distinct client_id,
case when text like '%обращение%' then dt end 'Обращение',
case when text like '%Отказ%' then dt end 'Отказ',
case when text like '%Одобрено%' then dt end 'Одобрено',
case when text like '%Проведено%'  then dt end 'Проведено',
case when text like '%Нет документов%' then dt end 'Нет документов',
case when text like '%Есть документы%' then dt end 'Есть документы'
from appeal
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка и как можно представить конечный результат в желаемый вид?

Comment: Какой признак позволяет определить, что вот именно эти записи следует собрать в одной итоговой записи? PS. Вообще-то это "условное агрегирование" - шаблон `SELECT признак, MAX(CASE WHEN категория = 'тип' THEN значение END AS тип), ... GROUP BY признак`

Comment: *Если делать "условное агрегирование" как вы посоветовали, то будет отбираться последнее обращение.* Это если его неправильно делать. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035), особенно пункт 2.3.

Comment: 1) Добавьте ссылку не в комментарий, а в текст вопроса. 2) Покажите требуемый ответ именно для этих данных (и не скриншотом, а текстом, форматированным в таблицу). 3) Пробовали составить запрос по показанному шаблону? если да - то покажите и его тоже. 4) Ответьте всё же на вопрос "Какой признак позволяет определить, что вот именно эти записи следует собрать в одной итоговой записи?". В фидле от 1 до 4 записей с одинаковым типом - какие собирать в одну запись и почему? PS. Первые две записи вообще полностью совпадают - это именно дубликат? или же две независимые, просто совпадающие, записи?

Comment: Остался вопрос о соответствии записей с различными типами. Как? См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=361a356f917f2c7951d4a279d9e540de) - данные отсортированы по дате-времени события. Тут вроде прослеживается группировка... но формально-то может быть, например, так - одно обращение, потом второе, потом два отказа - и как определить, какой отказ какому обращению соответствует? См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f47816284e830207dd626eea31af7f1a)

Comment: Укажите **точную** версию СУБД - покажите вывод `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (MS SQL, SQL Server) <> MySQL !!! И для него CREATE TABLE некорректен - он не знает про AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант для заявленного Microsoft SQL Server 2017:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Обращение' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY dt) grp
    FROM appeal
)
SELECT client_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Обращение' THEN dt END) [Обращение],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Отказ' THEN dt END) [Отказ],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Одобрено' THEN dt END) [Одобрено],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Проведено' THEN dt END) [Проведено],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Нет документов' THEN dt END) [Нет документов],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [text] = N'Есть документы' THEN dt END) [Есть документы]
FROM cte 
GROUP BY client_id, grp
ORDER BY client_id, grp
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72e6a069ad64d1780d0c726dbdb145a3

Comment: спасибо вам большое!